# $\forall x[P(x) \vee Q(x)]$ is not $\equiv (\forall xP(x) \vee ∀xQ(x))$

Tags: quantifiers

I have a question from a discrete math text,

Determine whether $\forall x[P(x) \vee Q(x)]$ and $\forall xP(x) \to \forall xQ(x)$ have the same truth value.

Thus far using the definitions from my book $\forall x[P(x) \to Q(x)] ≡ \forall x[\neg P(x) \vee Q(x)]$.

Now I've read a theorem that, $\forall x[\neg P(x) \vee Q(x)]$ is not $\equiv (\forall xP(x) \vee ∀xQ(x))$.

However, this to me does not constitute as proof, rather assumption.

Now my question, how do you prove  $\forall x[\neg P(x) \vee Q(x)]$ is not $\equiv (\forall xP(x) \vee ∀xQ(x))$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $Q(x)= \neg P(x)$

Then $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) \equiv \forall x (P(x)\rightarrow\neg P(x))\equiv \forall x\neg P(x)$.

While $\left(\forall x P(x)\rightarrow \forall x Q(x) \right) \rightarrow (\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall x \neg P(x))  $.

The second one is clearly unsatisfiable, while the first one is not.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example where $P(x)$ is '$x$ is odd' and $Q(x)$ is '$x$ is even', where the variable $x$ ranges over the integers. This example demonstrates both that
$$\forall x (P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)) \not\equiv (\forall x P(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x Q(x))$$
and that
$$\forall x (P(x) \vee Q(x)) \not\equiv (\forall x P(x)) \vee (\forall x Q(x))$$
since in both cases the left-hand side is true but the right-hand side is false.

You should try to work out the details, but let me know in the comments if you have trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i'm confused from where P(x) is 'x is odd' and Q(x) is 'x is even', where the variable x ranges over the integers.  How can   ∀x(P(x)⇒Q(x)) exist as a consideration?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... $\forall x(P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$ means "for all integers $x$, if $x$ is odd then $x$ is even", which is a false statement.

Comment: That's what I mean, isn't that the the example demonstration you posted?

Comment: Right, but $(\forall xP(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall xQ(x))$ is true, which demonstrates that the two are not equivalent.

Comment: I think I see the confusion in my understanding; this (∀xP(x))⇒(∀xQ(x)) seen as true.

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe (∀xP(x))⇒(∀xQ(x)) in words.  If all integers are odd, then all integers are even?

Comment: How can (∀xP(x))⇒(∀xQ(x)) exist as a consideration then?

Comment: I see by rules of nonsense?  If nonsense then nonsense is always true?

Comment: By general rules of implication, if p then q, p is false, and q is false, then the implication is true.

Comment: However, if I were state an axiom of consideration, ∀x(P(x)⇒Q(x)) cannot exist as a consideration, also (∀xP(x))⇒(∀xQ(x)) cannot exist as a consideration, therefore they are equivalent in that sense?

Comment: "If im not correct, then im not true". "If im wrong, then im not right". hmm

Comment: This is just a expression of  nonsense, as I could simply say, "If im not correct, then im right"  Then when or what is I'm.

Comment: If I'm not god then im not a human?

Comment: Thus according to our prescription to the "rules of implication", ∀x(P(x)⇒Q(x))≢(∀xP(x))⇒(∀xQ(x)), however their consideration does not exist.